# Javascript image open new window from bbcode

Tags: javascript, html, image, bbcode

Howdy I have this script

```
    var imageWindow;

function bbCodeImage(){

    imageWindow.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('                        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<html>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<head>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<title>'+link.getAttribute('imagedescription')+'</title>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('</head>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<body style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('  <p style="margin:0;padding:0;">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('    <img src="'+link.href+'" alt="'+link.getAttribute('imagedescription')+'" style="margin:0 auto;" width="'+link.getAttribute('imagewidth')+'" height="'+link.getAttribute('imageheight')+'">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('  </p>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('  <p style="margin:0;padding:5px;">');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('    <a href="#" onclick="window.close();">Close me.</a>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('  </p>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('</div>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('</body>');
    imageWindow.document.writeln('</html>');
    imageWindow.document.close();

    imageWindow.focus();

}       // End of LbImage() function.



var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function parsePage(){

  for(var n=0;n<links.length;n++){

    if(links[n].getAttribute('windowheight') && links[n].getAttribute('windowwidth') && links[n].getAttribute('imageheight') && links[n].getAttribute('imagewidth') && links[n].getAttribute('imagedescription')){

links[n].setAttribute('windowwidth',    Math.min(   parseInt(links[n].getAttribute('windowwidth')   ),screen.width-40)  );
links[n].setAttribute('windowheight',   Math.min(   parseInt(links[n].getAttribute('windowheight')  ),screen.height-60) );

      links[n].onclick=function(){
        imageWindow=window.open('','newwin','resizable=1,width='+this.getAttribute('windowwidth')+',height='+this.getAttribute('windowheight'));
        writePopup(this);
        return false;
      }     // End of the function that is run onclick of a "pop-up link".

    }       // End if statement that checks link for a "pop-up link".

  }     // End for loop.

}       // End of parsePage() function.
```

And I want to use it on my forum so that when a image is clicked it should open in a new window. The class/code in which the image is in is this

```
<img src="http://domain.com/attachments/1365693541700-jpg.15/" alt="1365693541700.jpg" class="bbCodeImage LbImage" style="">
```

Is there any way I can get this to work with the bbcode on my forum?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you put this code? At the end of the page or in a window.onload function?

Comment: I put it in a file and called it into the header template in my forum.

Comment: So no `window.onload` or something like that around it? If so.. then I think your `var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");` will be empty.

Comment: Hmm be much easier if I understood this better. The only thing I changed in the script was the function, I thought if I added the class name there it would work when someone clicked the image it would open in a new window. I guess I need to read up about this. I don't even know what windows.onload means so I can't answer that question sorry.